# How to center one image horizontally in a div using @media (min-width: 361px) and (max-width: 767px)?

Tags: html, css

The image I want to center horizontally is the frame1.png. It doesn't center well using margin-left:40%;or any other percentages. 
HTML CODE:

```
<div id="contents">
        <div class="content">
               <div class="content-about">
                   <div class="wrapper">
                       <div class="content-header">
                           <h2 class="font-GreatVibes">About <span class="font-GaramondPremierePro magenta">RESTO NAME</span></h2>
                           <h3 class="font-CormorantGaramond">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet, cnsectetur adipisicing elit. </h3>
                       </div>
                       <div class="content-content">
                           <div class="row">
                               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 content-img ">
                                   <img src="img/frame1.png" class="img-responsive"/>
                               </div>
                               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 content-text">
                                   <h3 class="font-CormorantGaramond">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h3>
                                   <p class="font-CormorantGaramond">Cnsectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt<br /> ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br /> quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea<br /> commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in<br /> voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br /> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa<br /> qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                   <p class="font-CormorantGaramond">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem<br> accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam,<br> eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto<br> beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. </p>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
    </div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
@media (min-width: 361px) and (max-width: 767px)
{
    .content-img img{max-width: 300px; max-height:300px; }
    .content-text{text-align: center;}
    .content-img img{margin-left:40% !important;}
    .content-img{max-width: 700px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this, so it is more transparent it centers the image inside...

Maybe I don't understand what you want to achieve. If you want to center the container it is in then apply it to the container... etc.
At least when I tried it it worked...

First delete this:

```
.content-img img{margin-left:40% !important;}
```

Then paste:

```
.content-img img{display: block; margin: auto; width: 40 %}
```

So it looks like this:

```
.content-img img{max-width: 300px; max-height:300px; }
.content-text{text-align: center;}
.content-img{max-width: 700px;}
.content-img img{display: block; margin: auto; width: 40 %}
```

[image]

Comment: i tried that before i asked a  question but i dont know why it still doesnt work :(

Comment: Delete the remaining code referring to margin. Because margin auto sets it in the middle

Comment: I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply center your image like this:

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Or, if have margin-top and/or margin-bottom values you want to preserve:

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

No [magic numbers](https://css-tricks.com/magic-numbers-in-css/) needed.

Comment: i tried that before i asked a  question but i dont know why it still doesnt work :(

Comment: Can you reproduce that issue in a Stack Snippet or JSFiddle so I can debug it?

Answer (score 0):

add style to image under media query

```
img{
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or

Add

```
img{
    display: inline-block
}
```

nothing more need to change